# JsRouting Bundle don't generate the good route

Tags: symfony

I'm using JsRouting bundle to generate Symfony2 routes in my Javascript files, the problem is that the generate function don't generate the server name in the route, this JS script:

```
Routing.generate('admin_terminal_error');
```

generate this url: /app_dev.php/admin/terminal/terminalErrorJson

How am I supposed to use it to generate also the server name, to use the url ?

I looked in the doc, and found this:

```
Routing.generate('admin_terminal_error', [], true)
```

it generate this url: http://localhost/app_dev.php/admin/terminal/terminalErrorJson

or it should generate this: http://localhost/**myproject**/app_dev.php/admin/terminal/terminalErrorJson

Here is my function in the controller:

```
<?php
      /**
      * Lists all TerminalError entities for datatable.
      *
      * @Route("/terminalErrorJson", name="admin_terminal_error", options={"expose"=true})
      * @Method("GET")
      * @Template()
      */
      public function datatableAction()
      {
          // ...
      }
```

Comment: can you access that routes from web? like twig template? what links it generating?

Comment: I access it from  http://localhost/myproject/app_dev.php/admin/terminal/terminalErrorJson, it's working normal.